# Access Token Request problem in Chrome Extension Manifest V3: Background.js Problem, Popup.js Works

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm implementing PKCE authentication for Spotify in my Chrome extension, using launchWebAuthFlow. I have a login page, which has a login button, clicking this initiates the authentication process, launches lawchWebAuthFlow. After succesful Authentication I want to store the token and load the main html. This is my manifest.json.

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "extentionName",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "some description",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "storage",
        "identity",
        "webRequest"
    ],
    "icons": {
        "16": "/images/icon_16.png",
        "48": "/images/icon_48.png",
        "128": "/images/icon_128.png"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "/images/icon_16_2.png",
            "48": "/images/icon_48_2.png",
            "128": "/images/icon_128_2.png"
        }
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "scripts/content.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "scripts/background.js"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": [
                "player.html"
            ],
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "oauth2": {
        "client_id": "my-client-id",
        "scopes": [
            "scope-1",
            "scope-2"
        ],
        "redirect_uri": "https://my-chrome-ext-id.chromiumapp.org/"
    },
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token/*"
    ]
}
```

Currently, I am making a POST request for an authorization code and then using this code another POST request for access token all from from popup.js, saving it in Chrome local storage, which works. This is how my popup.js looks rn which is working.

```js
// popup.js 
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Function to generate a random string of specified length
    async function generateRandomString(length) {
        const characters =
            "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        let result = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            result += characters.charAt(
                Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)
            );
        }
        return result;
    }

    // Function to generate a random code verifier
    async function generateCodeVerifier(length) {
        return await generateRandomString(length);
    }

    // Function to generate a code challenge from a code verifier
    async function generateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier) {
        function base64encode(string) {
            return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(string)))
                .replace(/\+/g, "-")
                .replace(/\//g, "_")
                .replace(/=+$/, "");
        }

        const encoder = new TextEncoder();
        const data = encoder.encode(codeVerifier);
        const digest = await window.crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", data);

        return base64encode(digest);
    }

    function loadPlayer() {
        // Redirect the popup to player.html
        const playerPageURL = chrome.runtime.getURL("player.html");
        window.location.href = playerPageURL;
    }

    // Function to initiate the login process
    async function initiateLogin() {
        const clientId = chrome.runtime.getManifest().oauth2.client_id;
        const scope = chrome.runtime.getManifest().oauth2.scopes;
        const redirectUri = chrome.runtime.getManifest().oauth2.redirect_uri;
        const state = await generateRandomString(16);
        const codeVerifier = await generateCodeVerifier(128);
        const codeChallenge = await generateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier);

        const authUrl = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&scope=${scope}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&state=${state}&code_challenge_method=S256&code_challenge=${codeChallenge}`;

        //POST request for authCode
        chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
            {
                url: authUrl,
                interactive: true,
            },
            (result) => {
                if (result) {
                    const url = new URL(result);
                    //extract authCode 
                    const authorizationCode = url.searchParams.get("code");
                    if (authorizationCode) {
                        try {
                            const body = new URLSearchParams({
                                grant_type: "authorization_code",
                                code: authorizationCode,
                                redirect_uri: redirectUri,
                                client_id: clientId,
                                code_verifier: codeVerifier,
                            });
                            //POST request for access token
                            fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
                                method: "POST",
                                headers: {
                                    "Content-Type":
                                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                                },
                                body: body,
                            }).then((response) => {
                                if (response.ok) {
                                    response.json().then((data) => {                                        
                                        chrome.storage.local.set({
                                            accessToken: data.access_token,
                                        });
                                        // Load the player on successful token exchange
                                        loadPlayer(); 
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.error("Error:", error);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    console.error("OAuth flow failed");
                }
            }
        );
    }

    //click event listener to the login button
    document
        .getElementById("loginButton")
        .addEventListener("click", initiateLogin);
});
```

However, after googling online, I learned that this process should be handled in a background.js service worker. So, I tried splitting the code between popup.js and background.js as mentioned below. The initiate function in popup.js now sends a message to background.js, and the request for the authorization code and access token has been moved to background.js. However, I'm encountering a 'fetch is not loading' issue, resulting in a 400 error".
I have checked paramenter before the post request to exchange auth code for token is being made and nothing is different than when the whole code was in popup.js. I am assuming its because the service worker runs in  different environemnt then popup.js. i want to ask how to do this the right way? Am i missing any permissions in my manifest.json?

```js
//popup.js split code

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Function to initiate the login process
    async function initiateLogin() {
        // Send a message to the background script to start the authentication
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "startAuthentication" });
    }

    // Add a click event listener to the login button
    document
        .getElementById("loginButton")
        .addEventListener("click", initiateLogin);

    // Listen for messages from the background script
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
        if (message.action === "authenticationComplete") {
            // Handle the completion of the authentication process          
            const { success, accessToken } = message;
            if (success) {
                // Authentication was successful, proceed to load the player
                loadPlayer();
            } else {                
                console.error("Authentication failed");
            }
        }
    });

    // Function to load the player
    function loadPlayer() {
        const playerPageURL = chrome.runtime.getURL("player.html");
        window.location.href = playerPageURL;
    }

    // Listen for messages from the background script or popup
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
        if (message.action === "generateCodeChallenge") {           
            // Function to generate a code challenge from a code verifier
            const codeChallenge = generateCodeChallenge(message.codeVerifier);          
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                action: "generatedCodeChallenge",
                codeChallenge: codeChallenge,
            });
        }
    });

    // Any other content script logic goes here
    async function generateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier) {
        function base64encode(string) {
            return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(string)))
                .replace(/\+/g, "-")
                .replace(/\//g, "_")
                .replace(/=+$/, "");
        }
        const encoder = new TextEncoder();
        const data = encoder.encode(codeVerifier);
        const digest = await window.crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", data);
        return base64encode(digest);
    }
});
```

here is the code that I moved to background.js

```js
//background.js split code

async function generateRandomString(length) {
    //same function as before
}

// Function to generate a random code verifier
async function generateCodeVerifier(length) {
    return await generateRandomString(length);
}
async function exchangeAuthCodeForToken(
    authorizationCode,
    clientId,
    redirectUri,
    codeVerifier
) {
    try {       
        const body = new URLSearchParams({
            grant_type: "authorization_code",
            code: authorizationCode,
            redirect_uri: redirectUri,
            client_id: clientId,
            code_verifier: codeVerifier,
        });
        const response = await fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
            body: body,
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP status " + response.status);
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        return data.access_token;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
        throw error;
    }
}

// Function to initiate the authentication process
async function startAuthentication() {
    // OAuth 2.0 authentication and token exchange logic
    try {
        const accessToken = await performAuthentication();
        // Notify the popup about the successful authentication
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            action: "authenticationComplete",
            success: true,
            accessToken,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle the error and notify the popup
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            action: "authenticationComplete",
            success: false,
            error: error.message,
        });
    }
}

// OAuth 2.0 authentication logic here
async function performAuthentication() {
    // OAuth 2.0 parameters
    const clientId = chrome.runtime.getManifest().oauth2.client_id;
    const redirectUri = chrome.runtime.getManifest().oauth2.redirect_uri;
    const scope = chrome.runtime.getManifest().oauth2.scopes;

    const codeVerifier = await generateCodeVerifier(128); // Implement this function
    let codeChallenge = "";
//doing this in poup.js because this function uses window.crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", data) which is not available in background environment.
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        action: "generateCodeChallenge",
        codeVerifier: codeVerifier,
    });
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
        if (message.action === "generatedCodeChallenge") {
            codeChallenge = message.codeChallenge;
        }
    });

    const state = generateRandomString(16);

    const authUrl = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&scope=${scope}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&state=${state}&code_challenge_method=S256&code_challenge=${codeChallenge}`;

    // To open the Spotify authentication page
    const result = await chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
        url: authUrl,
        interactive: true,
    });

    if (result) {
        // Extract the authorization code from the URL
        const url = new URL(result);
        const authorizationCode = url.searchParams.get("code");
        if (authorizationCode) {
            // Use the authorization code to exchange for an access token
            const accessToken = await exchangeAuthCodeForToken(
                authorizationCode,
                clientId,
                redirectUri,
                codeVerifier
            );          
            chrome.storage.local.set({
                accessToken: accessToken,
            });
            // Return the access token
            return accessToken;
        }
    }

    // Handle authentication failure
    throw new Error("OAuth 2.0 authentication failed");
}

// Listen for messages from the popup script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (message.action === "startAuthentication") {
        startAuthentication();
    }
});
```

Comment: There's no need to do it in the background context. You don't even need the background script (service worker) at all if this is all it does. The background script (service worker) is necessary only to handle various `chrome` events and a few other things that are impossible to do otherwise.

Comment: okay got it, thanks for responding